# 500 Internal Server Error in my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file with this

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|layout|avatars|custom|js|media|script|skin|uploads|isAjax|robots\.txt)
# To be deployed on LIVE only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
# Everything else to the CI controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But when I open my site, Show me :
**Internal Server Error**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

Thanks all for your Help.. :)

Comment: Try add lines one by one after "RewriteEngine on" and determine what line is the problem.

Comment: I checked sir, I try remove .htaccess but the problem still same.
I think script problem.. usually what problem caused this in script?
is it possible caused by server problem ?

Comment: Internal server error is not necesary caused by .htaccess file, the problem can be in server side code in one or serveral files of your web app, do you have your site in live url?

Comment: Yes.. Here is the site address http://top1script.net/
If you open there its says MOVED PERMANENTLY 301.

Comment: Yes.. Here is the site address http://top1script.net/
If you open there its says MOVED PERMANENTLY 301.
But if you use www .. like www.top1script.net
It's show that Internal Server Error